# how to add "max-width" to simplyscroll scroller <ul> jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

simplyScroll JS adds the inline CSS:

```
style="width:4400px;"
```

to the main  tag used and identified in the jQuery call. It gets the 4400px by adding the width of all of the children

s within this .

I would like to know where and what to add to the .js file to make it also add:

```
max-width:4400px;
```

so that it will look like:

```
style="width:4400px;max-width:4400px;"
```

You can view the .js file here:

https://raw.github.com/logicbox/jquery-simplyscroll/master/jquery.simplyscroll.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i never used simplyScroll .But you can try after line 145

```
this.$list.css(this.dimension,this.posMax+(this.itemMax*addItems) +'px');
```

add

```
this.$list.css('max-width',this.posMax+(this.itemMax*addItems) +'px');
```